# Using a "Class" member function as a Parameter for setInterval()

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, implicit

In Javascript is it possible to pass a member function into the function setInterval(). Hope this makes sense, I'll show you a code example of what I want to do because it's easier to explain that way.

I want to call the following function every 10 milliseconds & be able to access & alter the class member this.myArray() within that function(every time the function is called).

```
function myClass()
{
    this.myArray = new Array()
    setInterval(this.slideLoop, 10);
}

// THE WHOLE POINT OF ALL THIS IS SO I CAN ACCESS THE ARRAY this.myArray()    
// INSIDE THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION WHEN ITS CALLED FROM setInterval() EVERY 10ms
myClass.prototype.slideLoop = function()
{
    alert( this.myArray[0] );
    this.myArray.slice(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a closure with something like

```
function myClass()
{
    this.myArray = new Array()
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function() { that.slideLoop() }, 10);
}
```

For an example, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3gyXF/

(For the example I changed the timeout to 1s and the `slice` to `splice` to illustrate)